# PHP preg_replace() backreferences used as arguments of another function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to extract information from a tags using a regex, then return a result based on various parts of the tag.

`preg_replace('/<(example )?(example2)+ />/', analyze(array($0, $1, $2)), $src);`

So I'm grabbing parts and passing it to the `analyze()` function. Once there, I want to do work based on the parts themselves:

```
function analyze($matches) {
    if ($matches[0] == '<example example2 />')
          return 'something_awesome';
    else if ($matches[1] == 'example')
          return 'ftw';
}
```

etc. But once I get to the analyze function, `$matches[0]` just equals the string '`$0`'. Instead, I need `$matches[0]` to refer to the backreference from the preg_replace() call. How can I do this?

Thanks.

EDIT: I just saw the preg_replace_callback() function. Perhaps this is what I am looking for...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `preg_replace` like that.  You probably want [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = '/<(example )?(example2)+ \/>/';
preg_match($regex, $subject, $matches);

// now you have the matches in $matches and you can process them as you want

// here you can replace all matches with modifications you made
preg_replace($regex, $matches, $subject);
```